# Sequence contains no elements for Query with Multiple Elements Possible

Tags: c#, linq

I am new to Linq and C#, I've spent a very long time trying to solve this very simple problem.

I have the following code:

```
var currcard = from c in db.CreditCards where c.Id == cid select c;
```

Where db is a database context and credit cards is a table in that database.

This has the possible result of returning several records, which I then iterate through using a foreach. When there are records to be returned, everything works beautifully.

Sometimes, however, no records are returned, and I get the 'Sequence contains no elements' error. I don't want to use FirstOrDefault or SingleOrDefault, because I want ALL the records if they are returned. However, I cannot for the life of me figure out what equivalent to these functions I would use when I need null if NO records are returned.

I would not be surprised if the solution weren't simple. Sometimes c# seems overly complex.

**Edit:** In the end I discovered that the error was being thrown by the SaveChanges method on the context, not the assigning statement or iteration block. Using the Any keyword led me in the end to discovering my problem, so even though it turned out to be a separate issue, I've marked that answer as correct. But thanks to everyone for your assistance.

Comment: Which LINQ? LINQ to SharePoint?

Comment: What is the type of `CreditCards`, and where does it come from? There isn't anything in your code as shown which would normally throw a "Sequence contains no elements" error when `currcard` is iterated, so I suspect that `CreditCards` is hiding something more complicated.

Comment: I have edited the code slightly. CreditCards is a table in a database. It doesn't matter what table I use from my model, if there are no records being returned, I get the error. If I was returning one record all of the time, I could use SingleOrDefault or FirstOrDefault. But since I need all the records, not just one, I can't use these methods. I need to know which equivalent method to use when the sequence consists of more than one record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate over it without issues:

```
foreach (var r in currcard) // won't throw
```

Likewise, you can check beforehand if there are any items in the list:

```
if (currcard.Any()) // won't throw
```

Comment: The problem is that I'm being notified at the point currcard is assigned, not at the foreach.

Comment: This was the closest correct answer to what I was trying to ask, and led me in the end to figure out what I needed to know.

Answer (score 2):

If the sequence is empty and you iterate over it, nothing should happen, which is the semantic you usually want (and what you're looking for as well). What exactly is the iteration code you're using? A foreach shouldn't have any problems with an empty sequence.

Comment: It's not the iteration that has the problem. It's the execution of the code that tries to get the records. I'm being notified that nothing is returned when the where clause matches nothing. My code does not get to the foreach unless the sequence contains results.

Answer (score 2):

The Any() method will be true if the sequence contains elements. When working with databases it's usually a lot more efficient that using Count() > 0

```
var currcard = from c in CreditCards where c.Id == cid select c;

if (currcard.Any())  // do not be tempted to use currcard.Count() > 0
{
    // something with currcard; e.g.
    System.Console.WriteLine("Currcard");
    foreach(var card in currcard) // should do nothing if currcard has no elements
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: That will cause two queries to be issued if `currcard.Any()` is true, whereas `foreach` over an empty sequence will issue one query, then skip the body.

Comment: @SteveRuble that's true, so I've updated answer; I've got a feeling there's something else odd with the CreditCards - such as a deferred realization of the enumerable throwing an exception.

Comment: I've updated the code above slightly to explain that CreditCards is a table in a database. The foreach makes no difference when returning the error. The error is triggered when I try to execute the line of code in my question.